# Can't make an executable file in my assembly program (make: *** [makefile:31: HW1.axf] Error 1)

Tags: c, eclipse, assembly, arm, ds-5

So I'm having this error in DS-5 assembly, I cant seem to make an executable file whenever I build the project, this is the only error I can't fix in my program, I heard it has something to do with directories.

Heres an image

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pg726.png

Comment: Could you put the code in the question, not in an image?